# html editor that finds applied css

Tags: html, css, ide, editor, dreamweaver

Right now, I am using Notepad++ with two windows (page.html & page.css) - selecting an html tag I'd like to see the applied css for this specific tag, but with NotepadPlus I always have to scroll through deepest jungle of code.

The beavior I am asking for is similiar like with Firebug, when you inspect html and Firebug shows you the css applied on this specific tag.

The editor does not need to be complex, no wysiwyg.
(I know Dreamweaver is about visuality, but does it do the job?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have stumbled upon the functionality you require inside an editor called "Brackets". In your html file, if you target an html element, you can hit "Ctrl/Cmd + E" and you get the css for that specific element. And Brackets is a free to use Adobe editor. Hope this is what you are looking for.